# can i turn off terminal case sensitivity in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu's Terminal uses case-sensitive auto-completion, as I suppose would be expected for Linux.

But I think it would often be more convenient to use a case-insensitive one instead, to save you having to be accurate while starting a name, and would probably be worth the extra false positives. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. Questions about Ubuntu are better asked on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 6):

You can put this [`readline`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html) setting into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

---

You need to restart terminal to resource `~/.bashrc`. (or run `source ~/.bashrc` manually)

Comment: after "gedit ~/.bashrc", i put "set completion-ignore-case on" on the last line, and saved, but it is not working still !  how come ?

Comment: @FreshLover: Use the complete command; **bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'**. Save it and do 'source .bashrc'. It should work.